# Sorting multiple lines of String by date and time (e.g. messaging type of application)

Tags: java

I'd like to sort a string which contains more number of lines with this kind of pattern (I'd like to sort the messages in ascending order by date AND time (24hours format)):

> username1
>
> date1
>
> message1
>
> [this is empty line: "\n" ]
>
> username2
>
> date2
>
> message2

For example I have this kind of string:

> user1
>
> 15.11.2013, 13:34:00 (CET)
>
> Hello
>
> "\n"
>
> user2
>
> 10.11.2013, 10:00:05 (CET)
>
> Hi, how are you?
>
> "\n"
>
> user1
>
> 17.11.2013, 08:00:00 (CET)
>
> Not bad...

How to sort this long multiple-line string so that the newest messages will be on the bottom?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1) convert the string into individual message objects and put them into a a list or array, 2) sort them, 3) construct a string from the sorted messages

Comment: Please add the script you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the easiest solution would be to create Class representing one entry:

```
  public class ChatEntry implements Comparable<ChatEntry>{
    String message;
    String user;
    Date date;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ChatEntry other) {
      return date.compareTo(other.date);
    }
  }
```

now you can simply parse your string to these objects.
Put all objects to a List and use java.util.Collections.sort(List) to sort the messages and print them again

Comment: I'm getting Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.MyMaps.ChatEntry cannot be cast to java.util.Date . Could you maybe provide me with some example on how to implement this? THanks

Comment: Hi i made small mistake in comparable interface. please try it now

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a custom class, implement [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and then override the `compareTo` method, to compare the Strings, then you can simply call the `sort` method.